# web2py Form returns NoneType objects

Tags: python, web2py

```
form=FORM('Your name:',INPUT(_name='_name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
          'Your email:',INPUT(_email='_email', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
          'Your message:',INPUT(_message='_message', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
          INPUT(_type='submit'))
if form.accepts(request,session):
    response.flash = 'Your information has been sent successfully'
    message = [form.vars._name, form.vars._email, form.vars._message]
    mail.send(to='me@gmail.com', reply_to=form.vars._email,
        subject='Suggestion',
        message='<html>%s</html>' % message)
```

I'm having trouble creating a simple form that will email three fields to an account - "name", "email", and "message". When the form is submitted, only "name" is recognized and sent, while the other two variables always return NoneType objects. So, emails look like ['Person's Name', 'None', 'None']. I can't figure out how the last two variables differ from the first. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
INPUT(_name='_email', ...),
INPUT(_name='_message', ...),
```

The "_name" argument to the `INPUT()` helper translates to the "name" attribute of the `<input>` tag. So, `INPUT(_name='email')` will result in `<input name="_email">`, which will result in `request.vars._email` containing the value entered in the "_email" input field, which will then get copied to `form.vars._email`.